# Git branch reset

Tags: git, github, branch, reset, rebase

So the situation is as follows: I've checked out a new branch, let's call it **branch1**. I did some work on that branch, pushed the changes and made a pull request.

Later I made a new branch named **branch2**. But the problem was that I forked from **branch1**, instead of master. So when I made a pull request for **branch2**, it had all the commits of **branch1**. I realized what I had done, so I rebased **branch2** to master and now locally everything appears to be in order. Committing however is a bit of a pain, because local **branch2** is supposedly behind the remote **branch2**.

What would be the recommended solution in this case? Should I reset? If I reset on **branch2**, will that affect only **branch2**?

Comment: Rebase is pretty fine in my opinion.

Comment: If no one else has used **branch2** yet, you can `push --force` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips, I ended up using an interactive rebase with `git rebase -i HEAD~X` where X was the number of commits I wanted to edit. I proceeded to remove the commits I didn't want and did a force push with `git push -f`.